# Number of sequnces with given value

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

> Consider a valid string with bitwise operations (AND, OR, XOR), and also placeholders $X$, where each $X$ stands for an arbitrary number from $\{0,1\}$. There are $n$ many $X$s, so there are $2^n$ possible sequences. How many out of the 
>   $2^n$ strings have value $0$? How many have value $1$?

My approach to this problem was, I assumed that the interpretation of strings is done by associating left-to-right (that is, $0 \oplus 1 \land 0$ means $(0 \oplus 1) \land 0$).
I will use $\lor,\land,\oplus$ for OR, AND, XOR.

Let $s$ be an arbitrary string with $n$ many $X$s that evaluates to 0, and let $t$ be an arbitrary string with $n$ many $X$s that evaluates to 1.

Then, the strings with $n+1$ many $X$s that evaluate to $1$ are:
$$ t \lor 0, s \lor 1, t \lor 1, t \land 1, s \oplus 1, t \oplus 0. $$
The ones that evaluate to 0 are:
$$ s\lor 0, s\land 1, s\land 0, t\land 0, s\oplus 0, t\oplus 1. $$

Fixing a sequence of operations, let $S(n)$ be the number of strings with $n$ many $X$s that evaluate to 0 with the given operations, and let $T(n)$ be the number that evaluate to 1.

Denote the $i$'th operation by $O_i$. 
Then, just counting the combinations in the previous paragraph for each operator, I get the following recurrence relations:
$$
\begin{align}
&S(1)=T(1)=1 \\
&S(n+1),T(n+1) =
\begin{cases}
S(n), S(n)+2T(n) & \text{if } O_{n+1}=\lor \\
2S(n)+T(n), T(n) & \text{if } O_{n+1}=\land \\
S(n)+T(n), S(n)+T(n) & \text{if } O_{n+1}=\oplus
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

> What should I do if my assumption was wrong, that is, if the sequence could contain parentheses, e.g. $(X \lor (X \oplus X))$?

Comment: This question is very similar to a problem from an ongoing contest, which ends on 13th April: https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20B/problems/REBIT. It would be very helpful if the community refrains from discussing the solution of this problem till the 13th, so as to maintain fairness of the contest.

Comment: @nope, I encourage you to [edit] your question to provide the original source where you encountered this task.  This provides us helpful context.  Thank you!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61114700/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/123838/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

You should first build the [binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree#Boolean_expressions) of the given boolean expression. You can then do a [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on this tree, and start computing the answers from the leaves to the root (bottom to top), similar to the way you've done in your approach.

But instead of $S(i)$ denoting the number of assignments of the first $i$ $X$s which evaluate to 0, it will now be $S(u)$ denoting the number of assignments of the $X$s which lie in the subtree of $u$, which evaluate the expression until $u$ to be 0. Here $u$ refers to a node in the tree. Similarly $T(u)$ is defined for evaluation to 1.

The base case would be when $u$ is a leaf (which would happen when it corresponds to an operand), and both $S(u)$ and $T(u)$ would be equal to 1 in that case. Else, if $u$ is an internal node (which corresponds to an operator), you compute the $S$ and $T$ values by looking at the $S$ and $T$ values of its children, $c_1$ and $c_2$, and applying recursion similar to what you had in your answer:

If $u$ is an OR node,

$S(u) = S(c_1)  S(c_2)$

$T(u) = S(c_1)  T(c_2) + T(c_1)  S(c_2) + T(c_1)  T(c_2)$

If $u$ is an AND node,

$S(u) = S(c_1)  T(c_2) + T(c_1)  S(c_2) + S(c_1)  S(c_2)$

$T(u) = T(c_1)  T(c_2)$

If $u$ is an XOR node,

$S(u) = S(c_1)  S(c_2) + T(c_1)  T(c_2)$

$T(u) = S(c_1)  T(c_2)  + T(c_1)  S(c_2)$

And the final answer would be $S(\mathit{root})$ and $T(\mathit{root})$.